# get special colored text in textview swift

Tags: swift, text, colors, get, textview

I am new. I have a question. I have a text in textview with 3 colors. Example:

[image: 'Button' and 'Button2' at top of screen, then 'hello (red) every (green) one (black)' near center.]

When I click the button, it will show:

- the text has a red color is: hello
- the text has a green color is: every
- the text 'one' has a black color is: one

Comment: Have you tried `NSAttributedString `?  check out this article https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/113/nsattributedstring-by-example

Comment: thank you, I try, but I can't do that. can you help me answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the following:

```
var fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")

let helloString = NSAttributedString(string: "hello", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
let everyString = NSAttributedString(string: "every", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.green])
let oneString = NSAttributedString(string: "one", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])

fullString.append(helloString)
fullString.append(everyString)
fullString.append(oneString)

label.attributedText = fullString
```

But there is other stuff you may want to learn https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/113/nsattributedstring-by-example

Comment: Thank you but my point is not to display the text with 3 colors. I mean, we have a text with 3 colors available. displays which letters are in red, any words are green, and words are black. lịke video https://youtu.be/OyaWBtTsCZQ